# Get Exception Type

Tags: c++, error-handling, try-catch

I was wondering if there's a way to get an string representation of an errors type/name from `std::exception`. Let's say I catch `std::exception &err`, is there a way to say something like `err.getName()` or `err.getType()`. I have a project that can throw a wide variety of errors, but I want to get the exact type if it has not been caught by something else. I'll show what I generally mean.

For simplicity sake, let's say `libraryA` has several uniquely defined exception types (`libraryA::Exception_#` where `#` is replaced by a number to uniquely identify the error).

Here's some simple code for this:

```
try{
    doSomeTaskThatMightThrowAnError();
}catch(libraryA::Exception_1 &err){
    std::cout << "Error type 1: " << err.what() << std::endl;
}catch(libraryA::Exception_2 &err){
    std::cout << "Error type 2: " << err.what() << std::endl;
}catch(libraryA::Exception_3 &err){
    std::cout << "Error type 3: " << err.what() << std::endl;
}catch(std::exception &err){
    std::cout << "Unknown error: " << err.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Is there some way within `catch(std::exception &err)`'s block that I can say `std::cout << "Unknown error type: " << err.getType() << '\n' << "Error message: " << err.what() << std::endl;`

I want to catch `std::exception` as a precaution in case nothing else catches the error, but I want to be able to identify the exact error type so I may update my code and include another catch statement for it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use `typeid(e).name()` (remember to include `<typeinfo>` header).

But very little is guaranteed about the name so produced.

With Visual C++ it's nice and readable, with g++ it's mangled so that you practically need to use some compiler-specific functionality to demangle it.